# How to solve use-cases when componentWillMount is actually needed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router-v4

React is going to drop `componentWillMount`, `componentWillReceiveProps`, `componentWillUpdate` lifecycle hooks. More details can be found in [Update on Async Rendering](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html) article.

I have a question about migrating from these methods. Here's an example:

Currently, I use [`nprogress`](http://ricostacruz.com/nprogress/) for showing a progress bar on top of the page. It's used like this:

```
export default class Page extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    Nprogress.start();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Nprogress.done();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    )
  }
}
```

In the example above, I start showing progress bar before component's mounting and finish it when the component has been mounted.

How can I migrate to new React lifecycles and keep my components work as expected?

Comment: Judging from the react-router tag, this is for SPA navigation? I would then call `.start()` from the click event that causes the navigation, and `done()` from `componentDidMount`, like you have. You'll need to keep track/cancel out erroneous clicks and such, but that should work and IIRC, is how GitHub and the like do it.

Comment: Any reason you can’t put `Nprogress.start` in your constructor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use constructor:

```
export default class Page extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    Nprogress.start();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Nprogress.done();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use new static method called [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops). If you don't need to update your state just return `null`.

So, in your case:

```
export default class Page extends React.Component {

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
     if (!prevState.isMounted) {
        Nprogress.start();

        return {
          isMounted: true
        }
     }

     return null;
  }

  constructor(props) {
     super(props);

     this.state = {
        isMounted: false,
     }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Nprogress.done();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    )
  }
}
```

Hope it will helps.